# why is it right to say ""mark someone's emergence as a crusader"?

Tags: verbs, phrases

> The Everglades: River of Grass. Published in 1947, the book educated the nation about the dangers facing one of the most fragile ecosystems and **marked its author's emergence as a famous conservation crusader.** (From ACT test)

Why is it "mark someone's emergence as a crusader"? I don't think "sb's emergence" is in coordination with "a crusader".

Comment: It was from this book that the author first became well-known as a campaigner for conservation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence is grammatical and semantically fine. I think you are reading the last part as

> [T]he book... marked [its author's emergence] as [a famous conservation crusader].

In fact, it is meant to be read as:

> [T]he book... marked [its author's [emergence as a famous conservation crusader]].

"Emergence as a famous conservation crusader" is a noun phrase, inside another noun phrase "its author's emergence as a famous conservation crusader" the entirety of which was marked by the book.